# sum value from multiple array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can anyone help me on how to sum and then divide by the length of the array to get the average between dynamic multiple array of objects in javascript, the structure of my data as below. (example two array of objects, but might be more then 2 array of object)

```
"result": [
    {
        "id": "ioimall",
        "color": "hsla(147, 47%, 55%, 1)",
        "data": [
            {
                "x": "2023-04-01",
                "y": 13.3202
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-02",
                "y": 11.8434
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-03",
                "y": 17.2365
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-04",
                "y": 13.2256
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-05",
                "y": 23.9547
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-06",
                "y": 17.1793
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-07",
                "y": 15.776
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-08",
                "y": 11.3356
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-09",
                "y": 6.6018
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-10",
                "y": 4.3196
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-11",
                "y": 4.8547
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-12",
                "y": 4.1935
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-13",
                "y": 4.6628
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-14",
                "y": 5.9717
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-15",
                "y": 3.8766
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-16",
                "y": 3.6379
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-17",
                "y": 4.7511
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-18",
                "y": 5.2891
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-19",
                "y": 4.7904
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-20",
                "y": 7.5441
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-21",
                "y": 191.0336
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-22",
                "y": 0
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-23",
                "y": 0
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-24",
                "y": 0
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-25",
                "y": 0
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-26",
                "y": 0
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-27",
                "y": 0
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-28",
                "y": 0
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-29",
                "y": 0
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-30",
                "y": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "mytown",
        "color": "hsla(221, 79%, 74%, 1)",
        "data": [
            {
                "x": "2023-04-01",
                "y": 4.8123
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-02",
                "y": 5.5642
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-03",
                "y": 5.2656
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-04",
                "y": 8.7167
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-05",
                "y": 5.3078
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-06",
                "y": 4.7283
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-07",
                "y": 4.1322
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-08",
                "y": 5.1783
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-09",
                "y": 5.2504
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-10",
                "y": 6.7794
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-11",
                "y": 5.0806
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-12",
                "y": 4.9803
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-13",
                "y": 4.3914
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-14",
                "y": 5.4071
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-15",
                "y": 4.939
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-16",
                "y": 4.4732
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-17",
                "y": 5.0562
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-18",
                "y": 5.0911
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-19",
                "y": 4.8266
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-20",
                "y": 23.4864
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-21",
                "y": 1185.7143
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-22",
                "y": 0
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-23",
                "y": 0
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-24",
                "y": 0
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-25",
                "y": 0
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-26",
                "y": 0
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-27",
                "y": 0
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-28",
                "y": 0
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-29",
                "y": 0
            },
            {
                "x": "2023-04-30",
                "y": 0
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

what I would like to sum/reduce is the key `y: (value1 + value2)/length` (to get the average) inside the key  `data`

Expected result as below:

```
"result": [
{
    "id": "average",
    "color": "hsla(147, 47%, 55%, 1)",
    "data": [
        {
            "x": "2023-04-01",
            "y": 9.06
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-02",
            "y": 8.70
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-03",
            "y": 11.25
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-04",
            "y": 10.97
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-05",
            "y": 14.63
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-06",
            "y": 10.95
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-07",
            "y": 9.95
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-08",
            "y": 8.25
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-09",
            "y": 5.92
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-10",
            "y": 5.54
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-11",
            "y": 4.96
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-12",
            "y": 4.58
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-13",
            "y": 4.52
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-14",
            "y": 5.68
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-15",
            "y": 4.40
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-16",
            "y": 4.05
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-17",
            "y": 4.90
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-18",
            "y": 5.19
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-19",
            "y": 4.80
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-20",
            "y": 15.51
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-21",
            "y": 688.37
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-22",
            "y": 0
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-23",
            "y": 0
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-24",
            "y": 0
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-25",
            "y": 0
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-26",
            "y": 0
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-27",
            "y": 0
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-28",
            "y": 0
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-29",
            "y": 0
        },
        {
            "x": "2023-04-30",
            "y": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

],

Comment: Why is `"color": "hsla(147, 47%, 55%, 1)"` there in the expected result?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+sum+object+values+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always have all x values represented in each of the data arrays:

Start with the first data array, and look at each x value. Then, locate all matching objects with that x value. Use reduce to add them together to compute the average.

```js
const arr = [{"id":"ioimall","color":"hsla(147, 47%, 55%, 1)","data":[{"x":"2023-04-01","y":13.3202},{"x":"2023-04-02","y":11.8434},{"x":"2023-04-03","y":17.2365},{"x":"2023-04-04","y":13.2256},{"x":"2023-04-05","y":23.9547},{"x":"2023-04-06","y":17.1793},{"x":"2023-04-07","y":15.776},{"x":"2023-04-08","y":11.3356},{"x":"2023-04-09","y":6.6018},{"x":"2023-04-10","y":4.3196},{"x":"2023-04-11","y":4.8547},{"x":"2023-04-12","y":4.1935},{"x":"2023-04-13","y":4.6628},{"x":"2023-04-14","y":5.9717},{"x":"2023-04-15","y":3.8766},{"x":"2023-04-16","y":3.6379},{"x":"2023-04-17","y":4.7511},{"x":"2023-04-18","y":5.2891},{"x":"2023-04-19","y":4.7904},{"x":"2023-04-20","y":7.5441},{"x":"2023-04-21","y":191.0336},{"x":"2023-04-22","y":0},{"x":"2023-04-23","y":0},{"x":"2023-04-24","y":0},{"x":"2023-04-25","y":0},{"x":"2023-04-26","y":0},{"x":"2023-04-27","y":0},{"x":"2023-04-28","y":0},{"x":"2023-04-29","y":0},{"x":"2023-04-30","y":0}]},{"id":"mytown","color":"hsla(221, 79%, 74%, 1)","data":[{"x":"2023-04-01","y":4.8123},{"x":"2023-04-02","y":5.5642},{"x":"2023-04-03","y":5.2656},{"x":"2023-04-04","y":8.7167},{"x":"2023-04-05","y":5.3078},{"x":"2023-04-06","y":4.7283},{"x":"2023-04-07","y":4.1322},{"x":"2023-04-08","y":5.1783},{"x":"2023-04-09","y":5.2504},{"x":"2023-04-10","y":6.7794},{"x":"2023-04-11","y":5.0806},{"x":"2023-04-12","y":4.9803},{"x":"2023-04-13","y":4.3914},{"x":"2023-04-14","y":5.4071},{"x":"2023-04-15","y":4.939},{"x":"2023-04-16","y":4.4732},{"x":"2023-04-17","y":5.0562},{"x":"2023-04-18","y":5.0911},{"x":"2023-04-19","y":4.8266},{"x":"2023-04-20","y":23.4864},{"x":"2023-04-21","y":1185.7143},{"x":"2023-04-22","y":0},{"x":"2023-04-23","y":0},{"x":"2023-04-24","y":0},{"x":"2023-04-25","y":0},{"x":"2023-04-26","y":0},{"x":"2023-04-27","y":0},{"x":"2023-04-28","y":0},{"x":"2023-04-29","y":0},{"x":"2023-04-30","y":0}]}]

console.log({
  id: 'average',
  data: arr[0].data.map(({x})=>({
      x,
      y: arr.map(i => i.data.find(j => j.x===x).y)
            .reduce((a,c) => a+c) / arr.length
    })
  )}
)
```